# How do you get the EmotionSoiD app to load the BIOS?

Tags: root-access, file-system, emulators

I downloaded an app called EmotionSoiD which is supposed to be a PS2 emulator for Android here:

https://app.box.com/emotionsoid

I got it and it installed and runs and stuff, but a black screen pops up that says to load the EmotionSoiD BIOS, but it doesn't give an option to do so within the app...

I read another forum and it said that you might have to possibly put the file in the /data folder, but you can't access that without root and I can't risk rooting my phone.

I tried contacting the developer but I can't find any email/etc. What else can I do now????!!!

Answer (score 1):

The app is most likely asking you for PS2's original BIOS files. Usually BIOS files are copyrighted by the manufacturer, and are illegal to distribute.  You will have to do your own [research](https://www.google.com/search?q=PS2%20bios%20files&oq=PS2%20bios%20files) on how to obtain them.

Your best bet of getting developer's support is over at their [SourceForge site](http://sourceforge.net/projects/emotionsoid/), which seems to be the origin of the app.